# Perl package not found with apt

Tags: apt, package-management, perl

When I try to do an upgrade or install something, apt(-get or aptitude) throw an error, saying that perl can't find XML/SAX/Debian.pm while trying to configure libxml-libxml-perl. Here is the full error message :

```
configuring libxml-libxml-perl (2.0108+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Can't locate XML/SAX/Debian.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::SAX::Debian module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1/i686-linux-5.20.0-thread-multi-ld /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.20.1/i686-linux-5.20.0-thread-multi-ld /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.20.1 .) at /usr/bin/update-perl-sax-parsers line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/update-perl-sax-parsers line 19.
dpkg: error processing libxml-libxml-perl (--configure) :
 sub-process script post-installation installed returned an error code 2
Errors have been encountered during execution :
 libxml-libxml-perl
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried to remove (and purge) libxml-libxml-perl, it didn't work.

Then I've found (in debian package) and copy Debian.pm to `/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1/XML/SAX/`.

It fixed the error but an other one appeared :

```
Configuring libxml-libxml-perl (2.0108+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1) ...
update-perl-sax-parsers: Non-vendor version of XML::SAX is installed.
update-perl-sax-parsers: Automatic registration of SAX parsers might not work.
update-perl-sax-parsers: Registering Perl SAX parser XML::LibXML::SAX::Parser with priority 50...
Can't locate XML/LibXML/SAX/Parser.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::LibXML::SAX::Parser module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1/i686-linux-5.20.0-thread-multi-ld /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.20.1/i686-linux-5.20.0-thread-multi-ld /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.20.1 .) at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1/XML/SAX.pm line 147.
dpkg: error processing package libxml-libxml-perl (--configure) :
 sub-process script post-installation installed returned error code 2
configuring de libgles1-mesa:i386 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4) ...
configuring de libshine3:i386 (3.1.0-2) ...
configuring de libva-drm1:i386 (1.4.0~trusty) ...
configuring de libvncclient0:i386 (0.9.9+dfsg-6~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa1) ...
Processing triggers (« triggers ») for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors have been encountered during execution :
 libxml-libxml-perl
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried `dpkg-reconfigure` but:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure libxml-libxml-perl
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: libxml-libxml-perl is broken or not fully installed
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

Thanks for your answers.

P.S. : some message in the error message were in french and I have translated them They might not be exactly the same as the english error message.

**EDIT**:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure libxml-libxml-perl` give me this : `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: libxml-libxml-perl is broken or not fully installed`.

and

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxml-libxml-perl` gives :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for libxml-libxml-perl:i386
```

Comment: Does `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libxml-libxml-perl` help? Also, you can get errpr messages in English by running the command with `LC_ALL=C`. For example: `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install gedit`.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libxml-libxml-perl` give me this : `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: libxml-libxml-perl is broken or not fully installed`

Comment: Hmm. OK. I'm not sure where this is needed but will it let you reinstall it? Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxml-libxml-perl`. Also, please don't add extra information in comments. When someone asks you for more info, [edit] your question and include it there. Comments can be deleted without warning and are much harder to read. Once you have edited, you can leave a comment telling the commenter that you have done so (ping them by name: @terdon).

Comment: @terdon I've added the result of `apt-get install --reinstall ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a year old, but didn't see it "solved" or a solution in it. Also, this regression seems to keep happening with system upgrades, its been around for over a decade now.
You can install (or re-install) the `XML::SAX` module by running

```
sudo cpanp -i XML::SAX
```

When it completes you should be able to reinstall `perl-xml-libxml` without errors with

```
sudo apt-get install - reinstall perl-xml-libxml
```

.

Comment: Or `sudo cpan -i XML::SAX`, etc.